# "Field BackGroundElement.speed is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017

Getting this while trying to make a game on Unity, I pretty much copied this code from a source, yet it's still not working can anyone explain why?

It's underlined green and its speed;

This is also happening on another field labled backgroundElements;

```
public class BackgroundElement : MonoBehaviour{

[SerializeField]
private float **speed;**

public void Move()
{

    transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed * Time.smoothDeltaTime);
}
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
private BackgroundElement[] backgroundElements;

void Start()
{

}

void Update()
{
    if (true)
    {
        foreach (BackgroundElement element in backgroundElements)
        {
            element.Move();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you never assign a value to `speed`, it will remain at its default value, which for `float` is 0.

Comment: Well I have the field SerializeField above it so I can change it in unity